# Flask-SQLAlchemy fetch parent with children with one query

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Having:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", lazy='joined')

@dataclass
class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('parent.id'),nullable=False)
```

How possibly I can get this result preferably with one query:

```
[
  Parent {
    ...
    child: Child
  },
  Parent {
    ...
    child: Child
  }
]
```

If I do this it prints all the children, but it doesn't include it to the response.

```
parents = Parent.query.options(joinedload(Parent.children)).all()

for parent in parents:
    print("CHILDREN: ", parent.children.all())

return make_response(jsonify(parents))
```

Comment: Have you tried `children = relationship("Child", lazy='joined')` as described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#configuring-loader-strategies-at-mapping-time)?

Comment: Assuming I don't need to rerun migrations it doesn't change anything

Comment: I updated my question with more accurate code

Comment: I've used this exact method quite a bit to do joined loads (though in many cases went back- a bunch of smaller queries wound up being faster than one big one). I did notice something- why are your models annotated with dataclass? I am not at all sure how that magic would play with the sqlalchemy magic... either way, what is the actual output of your test snippet? include both the "print children" part and the jsonify version.

Answer (score 2):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

query(User).options(joinedload(User.orders))
```

(this is the example [from the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload), it assumes that "orders" is a relationship object on the model.)

As mentioned in the comment, you can define this directly on the model as the default behavior for the relationship with the "lazy" attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn’t work in my case. I updated question added imports and how models exactly look like.